# Python error AttributeError: module 'ntpath' has no attribute 'basepath'

Tags: python, python-os

Hello I am trying to split a path into directory and filename, on Windows. I am using the [os.path.basepath](https://appdividend.com/2022/01/29/python-os-path-basename/) API to accomplish that on Windows, but I am getting this error.

I tried upgrading pip3 followed by os_sys module, but still getting this error. Anyone can help me understand what is going on with `os.path.basepath` on Windows 11?

I have exhausted google search and reading blogs over this, but nothing is working at this point.

```
Python 3.9.13 (tags/v3.9.13:6de2ca5, May 17 2022, 16:36:42) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os.path
>>> os.path.basepath("c:\node\text.txt") 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'ntpath' has no attribute 'basepath'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two items:

1. if by 'basepath', you want the path, use `dirname` (if you want to parent directory of `text.txt`)  or `basename` if you just want the filename.
2. Use either `\\` for windows paths or use a raw string.

i.e.

for dir:

```
import os

os.path.dirname("c:\\node\\text.txt")
```

for filename:

```
import os

os.path.basename("c:\\node\\text.txt")
```

or

for dir:

```
os.path.dirname(r'c:\node\text.txt')
```

for filename:

```
os.path.basename(r'c:\node\text.txt')
```

I apologize as I wasn't too clear on whether you want the dirname or filename.

Comment: Nope. same error:
```>>> import os
>>> os.path.basepath("c:\\node\\text.txt")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'ntpath' has no attribute 'basepath'
>>> os.path.basepath(r'c:\node\text.txt')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'ntpath' has no attribute 'basepath'```

Comment: my bad.  Should use ```dirname``` or  ```basename```

Comment: thanks for point that out, I have accepted your response.

Answer (score 0):

Your Windows uses `ntpath`, read more information in [os.path link](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/os.path.html)

So, use this to get `basename` or `dirname` in your machine

```
import ntpath
ntpath.basename(r"c:\node\text.txt")
# result: text.txt
```